# How do I set up an SQL schema to compare imported XML items to prevent duplicates when stored to the database?

Tags: php, sql, xml, import

I'm importing schedule items into a database through a PHP script. The items have an XML structure like this:

```
<item>
  <date>1/1/2012</date>
  <time-start>1:00</time-start>
  <time-end>2:00</time-end>
  <title>One</title>
</item>
<item>
  <date>1/1/2012</date>
  <time-start>2:00</time-start>
  <time-end>3:00</time-end>
  <title>Two</title>
</item>
```

I will add each item as a record to the database. The problem arises because I don't have a unique row ID for each item so when I download and import the items later I make duplicate records.

My first solution is test before adding each item if at a certain date and item a title is scheduled. It just seems like a lot of processing to import several hundred records at a time when many will be duplicates.

Should I use the first item's date and start-time and the last item's date and start-time in WHERE clause to create an array of items to check each of the newly imported items against?

Answer (score 1):

If the combination of date, start time and end time should be unique, you can setup a unique index containing multiple rows in your database.

Note that you cannot use this if one or more of your columns allow NULL values. It would be possible to add more than one row having the same other values and one NULL value, because NULL !== NULL in database logic.

Comment: I'm going to combine the start time with the date and end time with the date to make a datetime datatype. If I define the UNIQUE key as start time, end time and title, then the INSERT query will not act on duplicates?

Comment: It will report a duplicate key error, which is exactly what you want in this case.

Comment: What happens if title 'One' is scheduled for the 3:00 o'clock slot too? In this case, the start time and end time are unique but the title is repeated.